# Solving the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x) \int_0^x e^{t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you please help me solve the limit below?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} (1/x) \int_0^x e^{t^2}dt$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_c^xf(t)dt=f(x)$$

Then, try L'H Rule.

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(t)$ be an antiderivative of $e^{t^{2}}$.

Then $ \displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} e^{t^{2}} \ dt = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{F(x)-F(0)}{x-0} = F'(0) = e^{0}= 1 $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: L'Hopital AND The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Answer (score 2):

L'Hopital's rule has already been mentioned, but you can also use Taylor series. For example:

$$e^{t^2} = 1+ t^2 + O(t^4)$$

$$\int_0^x e^{t^2} = x+\frac{x^3}{3} +O(x^5) $$

$$\frac{1}{x} \int_0^x e^{t^2} = 1 + O(x^2).$$

Taking the limit as $x$ goes to zero gives $1$.